# V-model not working in ant design input component vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, antd, antdv

I am working with vue 3 and ant design 2x. I am tired trying this code. And I follow vue documentation, I feel something miss. I am stuck with this problem. I hope your conclusion.

```
           <a-form
               :model="form"
               @submit="handleSubmit"
           >
               <a-form-item class="mb-10">
                   <a-input
                       type="text"
                       v-model="form.name"
                       placeholder="Name"
                   >   
                   </a-input>
                   <a-button type="primary" block html-type="submit">
                       SUBMIT
                   </a-button>
           <a-form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending plenty of hours, I got the solution from antv example in ant documentation.
I update code like this.
Different is I update  `v-model="form.name"` to  `v-model:value="form.name"`

```
           <a-form
           :model="form"
           @submit="handleSubmit"
        >
           <a-form-item class="mb-10">
               <a-input
                   type="text"
                   v-model:value="form.name"
                   placeholder="Name"
                 >   
               </a-input>
               <a-button type="primary" block html-type="submit">
                   SUBMIT
               </a-button>
       <a-form>
```

Comment: I don't see the difference. This code block is identical to the one in the question (other than whitespace).

Comment: @tony19 Thanks for mention that, my bad I update code block. Different is I update  `v-model="form.name"` to  `v-model:value="form.name"`